# Integrate Java executable into Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio

Is there any way to integrate eclipse plugin(as any form like executable) into visual studio? Simply, is it possible?

Comment: Please don't vandalize questions like this by editing. All below answer will become invalid. You are welcome to ask new question. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating java executable in visual studio? Do you mean running java application from application developed in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

No, the plugins are developed for eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot for following reasons:

1. Eclise is compeletly developed on Java where as Visual Studio is developed using C/C++ (and other technologies) which are different technologies.
2. Eclipse plugin's are in JAR file format, which is basically in-compatable with Visual Studio.
3. Eclipse plugins are exclusive to Eclipse (because it uses SWT etc.)

In short, NO you cannot use Eclipse plugins with Visual Studio. Hope this makes sense.